# Webserver on Raspberry Pi with ASP.Net Interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, raspberry-pi, windowsiot

I have developed a web server (C#) which runs on the Raspberry Pi (Windows IoT), but it can only send static HTML pages. Now, I want to render the pages dynamically using ASP.Net.

What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out my post "Step by step: Running ASP.NET Core on Raspberry Pi" here:  https://carlos.mendible.com/2017/03/21/step-by-step-running-aspnet-core-on-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run ASP.NET on Raspberry pi, you could take a look at ASP.NET Core.

> Arm32 support for .NET Core is still being brought up, but there are now daily runtime builds that are ready to use. There is no SDK that runs on ARM32 yet, but you can publish an application that will run on a Raspberry Pi.
>
> These steps have been tested on a RPi 2 and RPi 3 with Linux and Windows.

Full instructions and samples are available on [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md)

Comment: Thanks, is there also a library, which i can use directly in my project?

Comment: No dotnet core does not support the full. Net framework. Take a look at the docs